# Float class constructors

Tags: java, constructor

What is the difference between the ways in which we use the following 2 constructors in the wrapper class Float in java 
 `Float(float value)` and
 `Float (double value)`

Similarly between the 2 constructors
 `Float(double value)` and 
 `Double(double value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Float(float)` constructor creates a `Float` wrapper object with the given value. The `Float(double)` constructor creates and object with the given argument casted to `float`, losing some of the precision of the `double` value. From [the source](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html):

```
public Float(float value) {
        this.value = value;
}

public Float(double value) {
        this.value = (float)value;
}
```

The `Double(double)` constructor on the other hand creates a `Double` wrapper object with the given `double` value.

Answer (score 2):

[Have a look at source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.%3Cinit%3E%28float%29)

```
     public More ...Float(float value) {
480        this.value = value;
481    }


Constructs a newly allocated Float object that represents the argument converted to type float.
Parameters:
value the value to be represented by the Float.
488
489    public More ...Float(double value) {
490        this.value = (float)value;
491    }
```

just casting `this.value = (float)value;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific difference between Float(float value) and Float (double value), the latter just cast double parameter to float representation.

See source code of this methods:

```
public Float(float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Float(double value) {
    this.value = (float) value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the cross-type constructors is just a convenience for when you have a floating-point value of one precision and are needing an object holding the other one. Moving from `double` to `float` loses precision, and moving from `float` to `double` gains precision (but the actual value stored will just be padded with zeroes). The two constructors are the equivalent of manually casting to the other precision first.